# Using the intermediate value theorem to prove the presence of a root

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Prove that the below equation has a root in the given interval:

$\cos(\sqrt{x})=e^x-2$ in the interval $(0,1)$."

So I found that $f(1) = 0.54$  and $f(0) = 1$ for the left hand side.

But this did not seem to be the same as the right hand side. So how exactly can I prove it is continuous in the interval, and possibly go further and prove the presence of a root?

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that the statement is correct? Easily you can see that $f'(x)<0$ for every $x\in (0,1)$ so it's decreasing and it has a lowerbound 0.4, so it would never be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defining
$$f(x)=\cos(\sqrt{x})-e^x+2$$ then we have $$f(0)=2$$ and $$f(1)=\cos(1)-e+2\approx -0.17797<0$$
it is $$x\approx 0.9419081484$$

Comment: That is the mean-value theorem, not the intermediate value theorem. – How does this help to prove the existence of a solution of the given equation?

Comment: i think i have misreaded the question, sorry

Comment: it is $$\cos(0)-e^0+2=1-1+2=2$$